# About Ireland visa

Tags: visas, ireland, eu-citizens

Two days ago, I obtained a visa to enter Ireland as the husband of a European Union citizen. They sent me a letter saying that I can travel between 2024-02-01 and
2024-05-01. But I had made it clear in my visa application that I wanted to travel on 2024-04-23. Will this create an obstacle for me with the immigration officer at the airport?

---

Will the immigration officer give me permission to stay for three months starting from the day I arrived? Because I intend to apply for residency and settle there with my wife.

Answer (score 11):

> Will this create an obstacle for me with the immigration officer at the airport?

No, the visa allows you **to enter** Ireland within 90 days of issue.

You wish **to enter** Ireland 7 days before the issued visa expires.

> A single journey visa costs €60 and **will be valid for *one entry* to the State up to a maximum of 90 days from the date of issue**.

As a spouse of an EU citizen you may remain, **together**  with your spouse, as long as the spouse remains in Ireland.

> **Family members of EEA/Swiss citizens**
> If you are coming to Ireland to join or accompany your EEA family member, you must apply for a visa if you are from a country that is not in the list above.
> ...
> If you plan to stay in Ireland for more than 3 months you must apply for residence after your arrival.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa requirements for entering Ireland](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving-country/visas-for-ireland/visa-requirements-for-entering-ireland/)